# Does the $\max_x \min_\lambda L(x,\lambda)$ concept still work for inequality constrained optimization?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker, constraint-programming

When we want to maximize a function $f(x)$ with respect to $x$, and w.r.t a constraint $g(x)=0$ we can formulate the Lagrangian
$$L(x, \lambda) = f(x) + \lambda h(x)$$

And then maximize $L(x,\lambda^*)$ with respect to $x$, where $\lambda^*$ is the value that minimizes $L$ with respect to $\lambda$.

That is, The above equality constraint problem is equivalent to the problem:
$$\max_x\min_\lambda L(x,\lambda)$$

**My question is, does an analogous condition also exist for inequality constraints?** My intuition is no, because with the inequality constraint, we have the additional "complementary slackness" requirement, and I'm not sure how to fit that in.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is "Yes". You can still apply LP theory with inequality constraints. See [Equality and Inequality Constraints](http://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/classes/QUANT/NOTES/chap4/node6.html) or [Note](http://privatewww.essex.ac.uk/~wangt/Presession%20Math/Lecture%205.pdf).

Comment: my question was specifically about whether the $\max_x\min_\lambda L(x,\lambda)$ interpretation still works. I know that we can use Kuhn Tucker theorem to solve problems with inequality constraints.